# Trouble with serialization (The type of the argument object is not primitive)

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, serialization, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm writing an evolutionary algorithm but I'm having trouble writing some items in an XML file. The error I'm recieving is

> InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object
>   'ExperimentSettings' is not primitive.

This is the code I'm working with (I left out some methods that work and are not related with the issue in any way):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class SerializerTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spawner;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { Save(false, 0, 50, 5, 5, 50, 5, new Vector3(0, 20, 0), new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("/Experiments/Test #0"), spawner.GetComponent<CreatureGenerator>()); });
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Save(
        bool startCreatures,
        int experimentType,
        int totalCreaturesNo,
        int cycles,
        float experimentDuration,
        float survivorsPercentage,
        float probabilityOfMutation,
        Vector3 creaturesStartingPosition,
        DirectoryInfo saveFolder,
        CreatureGenerator generator
        )
    {
        //create file where to save the settings
        string settingsFile = Application.dataPath + saveFolder + "/settings_and_parameters.xml";

        if (File.Exists(settingsFile))
        {
            File.Delete(settingsFile);
        }

        XmlSerializer settingsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Creature));
        FileStream settingsStream = new FileStream(settingsFile, FileMode.Create);

        //save the settings
        ExperimentSettings thisExperiment = new ExperimentSettings()
        {
            startCreatures = startCreatures,
            experimentType = experimentType,
            totalCreaturesNo = totalCreaturesNo,
            cycles = cycles,
            experimentDuration = experimentDuration,
            survivorsPercentage = survivorsPercentage,
            probabilityOfMutation = probabilityOfMutation,
            creaturesStartingPosition = creaturesStartingPosition,
            saveFolder = new DirectoryInfo(saveFolder.ToString()),
            experimentScene = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name
        };

        settingsSerializer.Serialize(settingsStream, thisExperiment);

        //close the file
        settingsStream.Close();
    }
}
```

In the Start function I just set up a button that when clicked saves a file with some arbitrary parameters. I'm gonna leave that code there but it's not so pertinent with the error.

This is the class that returns the error when serialized:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ExperimentSettings
{
    public bool startCreatures;
    public int experimentType;
    public int totalCreaturesNo;
    public int cycles;
    public float experimentDuration;
    public float survivorsPercentage;
    public float probabilityOfMutation;
    public Vector3 creaturesStartingPosition;
    public DirectoryInfo saveFolder;
    public string experimentScene;
}
```

The thing that baffles me is that I tried serializing another class in the same method in the same way it actually worked. The next code block is the class that's being serialized correctly:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Creature
{
    public string creaturePrefab;
    public double result;
    public bool passed;
}
```

I tried removing all the variables from `ExperimentSettings` leaving an empty class but it still doesn't work. I'm all out of ideas, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seriously, an [MCVE] would be helpful. That exception is thrown on one line, show only the code that produces that error and its context.

Comment: @rene I edited the code to match as closely as possible the document you provided

Comment: Change         `XmlSerializer settingsSerializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof(ExperimentSettings));`

Comment: @boran yes thank you I just realized this myself!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!
In the line

```
 XmlSerializer settingsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Creature));
```

I copy pasted from my own code but I forgot to change the class, so to solve this particular problem I'd have to edit this line this way

```
XmlSerializer settingsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ExperimentSettings));
```